# How to recreate wildcard lines from `hexdump` output?

Tags: bash, python3, restore, hexdump

I have a problem: I have some old `hexdump`s laying around as text files.
I want to recreate the files they represent because I'm interested in what these files were.
The problem is: When I created these `hexdump`s I didn't know of the `-v` flag, so in some of the `hexdump`s some repeating lines are replaced with a `*`.

What I want is a way to programmatically recreate those lines using `bash` or `python3`.

I also have a concept no how to do it but I didn't manage to create a working script to recreate those lines.
My concept is:

1. Check the file for lines which are made up of only a `*`. (if there are none, jump to step 6)
2. Loop through the found lines:
3. Calculate the amount of lines that were replaced with that asterisk, by taking the offset numbers.
4. Copy the line above the asterisk the calculated amount of times and thereby replace the asterisk.
5. If there are asterisks left: repeat steps 3 and 4 for the next asterisk, otherwise do step 6:
6. Print out the completed hexdump.

###### Question:

Can someone please help me to create a script that does the above? Or a script that gives the same end result but works better?

Comment: see for example https://github.com/mfleetwo/reverse-hexdump

Comment: @frostschutz I cannot find the part of the code that recreates the lines, so I can have nice wildcard-less hexdump "repaired" automatically, but thanks for the tip to recreate the files!

Comment: You can either adapt it or just make a new hexdump from the output with the new settings.

Comment: @frostschutz "a new hexdump from the output" would give me a hexdump from which I could recreate the hexdump output from the original file. Or do you mean 1. recreate the file → 2. re-run hexdump with the new settings on the recreated file?